# Return worksheet names in tab order from closed file using ADODB

Tags: excel, vba, ado, adodb

I am able to connect and query specific sheets. Some files may have the first worksheet name different or changing and sometimes there may be more than one.

I tried a few different functions to return a full list. However none give me the worksheet tab names in the order they appear in Excel.

The easiest method is this.

```
Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
Set cat.ActiveConnection = objConnection
Debug.Print cat.Tables.Count

For Each tbl In cat.Tables
Debug.Print tbl.Name
Debug.Print tbl.datecreated
Debug.Print tbl.datemodified
Next tbl
```

I thought I could determine by datecreated or datemodified, but the dates on all 4 are the same.

```
> This prints for me:
> Avion$
> 3/17/2017 12:43:19 PM
> 3/17/2017 12:43:19 PM
> Meow$
> 3/17/2017 12:43:19 PM
> 3/17/2017 12:43:19 PM
> Sheet1$
> 3/17/2017 12:43:19 PM
> 3/17/2017 12:43:19 PM
> Sheet2$
> 3/17/2017 12:43:19 PM
> 3/17/2017 12:43:19 PM
```

So it gives me alphabetic sorting of the worksheet tab name list.

However the worksheet order is:

```
>[Sheet1][Avion][Sheet2][Meow]
```

I can't find any property to tell me the order.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/406243-get-sheet-number-using-adox.html

```
Sub GetSheetNames()
    '###Requires a reference to Microsoft DAO x.x Object Library

     Dim FName As String, i As Long, WB As DAO.Database

     FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ADOXSource.xlsx"


     Set WB = OpenDatabase(FName, False, True, "Excel 8.0;")

     With WB.tabledefs
         For i = 1 To .Count
             Debug.Print i, .Item(i - 1).Name '<< TableDefs Is zero based
         Next i
     End With

     WB.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I did figure this out yesterday using DAO and built a function actually... but I am surprised I can't do this with ADO. Since DAO will eventually be defunct and technically microsoft considers it abandoned it worries me...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I built the other day with DAO but I still want to figure out ADO...

```
Public Function GetSheets(ByVal FileToOpen As String, ByVal FileExt As String)
    Dim Shts() As String, ShtCnt As Integer: ShtCnt = 0
    ReDim Shts(0 To ShtCnt)

    Dim dbE As Object, db As Object, tbl As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set dbE = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine")
    Set dbE = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.35")
    Set dbE = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.36")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set db = dbE.OpenDatabase(FileToOpen, False, False, FileExt & ";HDR=Yes;")

    For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
       Shts(ShtCnt) = Mid(tbl.Name, 1, Len(tbl.Name) - 1)
       ShtCnt = ShtCnt + 1
       ReDim Preserve Shts(0 To ShtCnt)
    Next

    Set dbE = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set tbl = Nothing

    GetSheets = Shts
End Function
```

Then to run I have a bunch of code for an open dialog, then it determines the format and the strings:

```
Select Case Right(FileToOpen, Len(FileToOpen) - InStrRev(FileToOpen, "."))
    Case "xls", "XLS"
        Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        FileExt = "Excel 8.0"
    Case "xlsx", "XLSX"
        Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        FileExt = "Excel 12.0"
    Case "csv", "CSV"
        Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        FileExt = "Excel 8.0"
    Case Else
        GoTo Err:
End Select
```

Then I have:

```
'Get Spreadsheets
Dim FileSpreadsheets() As String    
FileSpreadsheets = GetSheets(FileToOpen, FileExt)
```

Then you can do whatever you need to do but as an example to get a msgbox:

```
mymsg = "Count: " & UBound(FileSpreadsheets) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Sheets:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

For Each Sheet In FileSpreadsheets
    mymsg = mymsg + Sheet & vbNewLine
Next Sheet

MsgBox mymsg
```