# Use approximation for sheetname in DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet to import an Excel document with multiple sheets into an Access table (Table1), and to do so you must specify them as part of the "Range" parameter of DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet.  However, these sheet names are not consistent across time, often containing some timestamp or other string that is not replicable.

Sheets within **ExcelDoc.xlsx**:

- 20210519172848_DataTable_ABC
- 20210519172921_FinancialTable_DEF

There is usually a consistent string within the sheet name.  e.g. "DataTable" and "FinancialTable".  I would like to specify the sheet name using these keywords, in a similar way that you can use the wildcard (*) to specify an Excel document using a keyword via the Dir() function.  However, this does not work:

```
Private Sub Project1()
    Importer("DataTable", "C:\Users\Myself\Documents\ExcelDoc.xlsx")
End Sub

Public Function Importer(Keyword As String, FPath As String)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, TableName:="Table1", FileName:=FPath, HasFieldNames:=True, **Range:="*" & Keyword & "*"
End Function
```

It thinks I'm looking for the sheet name *DataTable*.  I have seen some suggestions say that adding an "!" onto the end is necessary, but that seems to yield an name validity error because of an invalid character.  Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can use ADO to query the sheet names in an excel file - you can use that to determine the exact sheet name to use.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397158/connect-to-excel-with-ado-dont-know-sheet-names/1397181 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863639/return-worksheet-names-in-tab-order-from-closed-file-using-adodb

Comment: Thanks Tim and June7 - I posted an answer.  If I may, I have a follow-up question: will it cause problems to use the ActiveX references for something that users on other machines will use?  Are these carried over with the code, or are they specific to the user's machine (and thus something they will have to separately enable)?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

> ```
> Public Function SheetFinder(Keyword As String, FPath As String) As String
>     Dim oConn
>     Dim oRs
>     Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
>     Dim sConn
>     Dim SheetName As String
>     sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & FPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""
>     oConn.Open sConn
>
>     Set oRs = oConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
>     Do While Not oRs.EOF
>         SheetName = oRs.Fields("table_name").Value
>         If InStr(SheetName, Keyword) Then
>             SheetFinder = CStr(SheetName)
>             oConn.Close
>             Exit Function
>         Else:
>             oRs.MoveNext
>         End If
>     Loop
> End Function
> ```